# How to implement URL shortener with rails with two separate hostname?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-shortener

Let's say I have a domain, `foobargoo.com`, and I recently registered `fbg.co` so that I can add Url shortener to. I may have a lot of requests which has a route `foobargoo.com/requests/:id` which may end up be more than 100 character, and I would like to use something like `fbg.co/TxFj4` (which provides > 900 million strings) and redirect to the specific ID.

I am wondering if I can do it from within one rails codebase in the `routes.rb`, or do I have to add a new repo just to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems okay to have that in one code base. You certainly don't *need* to create separate project, but you may want to to speed up the redirection (for example by having light-weight Sinatra project instead of Rails).

In your `routes.rb` you can add shortened routes like this:

```
constraints(host: 'fbg.co') do
  get ':id', to: 'shortener#redirect'
end
```

Then use a simple action to handle redirects:

```
# shortener_controller.rb

class ShortenerController < ApplicationController
  def redirect
    redirect_to ShortLink.find_by_hash(params[:id]).url
  end
end
```

Of course, you need a model which will store short URLs and map them to full URLs as well:

```
class ShortLink
  # Migration for its creation is something like:
  #   t.string :hash
  #   t.string :path

  def url
    "foobargoo.com/#{path}"
  end
end
```